# Exposing services deployed on Service Fabric Cluster (with traffic distribution handled by an Internal Load Balancer)

Tags: .net, azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I have a Secure Service Fabric Cluster (I'm using self signed certificates for the moment) with a Internal Load Balancer deployed on azure which has all the rules and probes configured. Right now I do not have an internet facing load balancer or an equivalent resource that has a public IP which means I cannot access it from anywhere outside my VNet.

I need to expose the services deployed in my cluster without exposing the Service Fabric management URL (like westus.cloudapp.azure.com:19080).

From what I have found, my options are:

1. To use a Public Load Balancer
2. To configure my VPN Gateway
3. To use an Application Gateway

Option 1 would mean that I would have to replace my existing internal load balancer with an internet facing one (if that is possible) but that exposes my management url as well. Or I would have to go with a multi-tier app with a web tier and back end - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/load-balancer-internal-overview/

Option 2 would require me to configure access to my private IPs through the VPN gateway which I do not have access to.

Option 3 again seems to undermine the existing internal load balancer

Is there any way to custom-route my requests to the services using something that can be built on top of my existing architecture?

Comment: you could use a Network Security Group to block access to specific ports and allow access to ports you need and combine that with a internet facing load balancer? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Internet-facing load balancer and just configure it to only accept and forward traffic on the ports used by your public-facing services. Don't expose ports 19000 and 19080 (or whatever ports you configured your cluster with) through the load balancer if you don't want the management endpoints exposed. Hopefully you've [secured your cluster](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-security/#security-recommendations) so that even if an unauthorized user did get through to the management endpoints somehow, they would not have access to do anything.